# ImportError: No module named 'openpyxl'...python raspberry...aparece esse erro no raspberry no meu micro funciona bem...o que pode ser?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, openpyxl

Fiz um pequeno programa em python no meu note para usar com raspberry, testei e funcionou bem.......quando passo pro raspberry ele não encontra o arquivo openpyxl......ja instalei o openpyxl no raspberry pelo metodo sudo pip install openpyxl.........no note funciona bem no raspberry aparece esse erro abaixo:

Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

> > > ======== RESTART: /home/pi/Documents/Python Works/TestandoTkinter.py ========
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "/home/pi/Documents/Python Works/TestandoTkinter.py", line 5, in 
> > >           import openpyxl
> > >       ImportError: No module named 'openpyxl'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

experimenta fazer `pip3 install openpyxl`

Comment: E que caso a rasp tenha instalado python2 e python 3 a maneira como estas a utilizar o pip vai instalar por defeito no python2 e quando correres o python3 vai dar erro pk nao encotra o modulo

Comment: Oi Hugo deu certo...muito obrigado....

Comment: Marque como correta para ajudar as outras pessoas